# How to find the vector that passes through a point and is perpendicular to another vector.

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $ \mathbb{a} = i+4j-3k$ and $b = 7i+20j-12k$ be vectors and $A(2,5,-3)$ be a point. I want find the line $l_ 3$ passing through point $A$ wich is perpendicular to both veotors. How should I do this?

Comment: what is the line $1_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M(x,y,z)$ a point on the desired line then the vector $\vec{AM}=(x-2,y-5,z+3)$ is orthogonal to $a$ and $b$ so
$$\vec{AM}\cdot a=(x-2)+4(y-5)-3(z+3)=0$$
and
$$\vec{AM}\cdot b=7(x-2)+20(y-5)-12(z+3)=0$$
so the line is given by the  equations (intersection of two planes):
$$\left\{\begin{array}\\x+4y-3z=31\\
7x+20y-12z=150\end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Every vector perpendicular to $a$ and $b$ has to be collinear to $a \times b$ ([cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product)).

Answer (score 0):

The line takes the form $\left\{ \vec{u}+\lambda\vec{v}\mid\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $.

Here $\vec{u}=\left(2,5,-3\right)$ and $\vec{v}=\left(x,y,z\right)$
is perpendicular to $\left(1,4,-3\right)$ and $\left(7,20,-12\right)$.

That leads to the equations:

$x+4y-3z=0$ and $7x+20y-12z=0$.

They determine the direction of
$\vec{v}$.

When it comes to its length you can make your own choice.